LLVM: генерация исходного кода на C++
Подскажите, есть ли у LLVM API для генерации исходного кода на C++ по некоторому декларативному описанию? Под последним я понимаю что-то похожее на DSL, который используется в библиотеке для матчеров; или AST, если его можно собрать вручную и потом "заставить" LLVM сгенерировать по нему плюсовый код.

My First Language Frontend with LLVM - Там есть возможность генерировать сразу промежуточный код, без С++.

@user7860670, это не совсем то, что нужно. Мне нужен именно плюсовый код на выходе. Но, возможно, я Вас неправильно понял. Мне бы, скорее, подошел вариант "IR -> C++" :)

При разборе AST можно генерировать код на С++. А вообще, если DSL не особо сложный планируется, то заморачиваться с llvm наверное не стоит.

@user7860670, "При разборе AST можно генерировать код на С++" - Вы про API, который используется для рефакторинга? "А вообще, если DSL не особо сложный планируется, то заморачиваться с llvm наверное не стоит" - к такому же мнению пришел (с учетом того, что в LLVM ничего не нашлось, что прям совсем "dedicated").

На самом деле из AST будет проще генерировать сразу тест, нежели посредством API выстраивать структуру C++ и потом на ее основе генерировать текст.
